# What is the output of the following PHP code?

Tags: php

the output of the following code?

```
echo '1' . (print '2') + 3;
```

I tested and the result is 214, but why 214?

if I code:

```
echo (print '2') + 3;
```

the result is 24
Then, echo '1' . '24'; should be 124.

Confused...

Comment: Maybe, if you wrote sensible, maintainable code, you wouldn't have to ask questions like this :-)

Comment: These kind of questions are actually asked on the Zend PHP exam. Not the most sensible code, but interesting from a more theoretical perspective.

Comment: @Peter, Yes I saw such questions on the Zend exam, don't know why Zend exam asks such questions, maybe they think it's the PHP language basics? BTW, do you think Zend exam is worthy taking it?

Comment: @lamplanp Indeed I think they ask these questions because they're about the language basics. I found the exam quite useful, as my knowledge of PHP (basics, security, OOP, other things...) really grew during preparation of the exam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the expression is parsed, the "print" statement is immediately writing its output. So there's the first 2. By definition its return value is 1.

So then the remaining expression is the character 1, followed by the numeric expression 1+3. Therefore 1 and 4.

214

Comment: @lamplanp Please flag the answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks.